# declaring two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a couple of college assignments I am having trouble with.  Really I am just confused about one thing regarding an array.  I need to declare a three column, 5 row array.  The first two columns are integers and the third column is the letter grade. So I am very confused about declaring the data type since they are different. This is my first go-around with arrays, so please excuse my ignorance.  Here is an what my array is supposed to look like.

```
Column 1 {0,300,350,400,450}
Column 2 {299,349,399,449,500}
Column 3 {F,D,C,B,A}
```

(It's a grading app)

I can solve the rest of the problem myself, I am just confused about this array portion. So my question is strictly about how to declare such an array.  It say's to use a two-dimensional array which only confuses me more since there are three columns.  Thank you!

Comment: I think they say to use a 2-D *because* the range is integer/number and the letters are string.  I guess use a 2D for the range and another string array for the letter grade.  If the score falls in the range for `GradeRange(i)` then greade = `Grades(i)`.  Even 2D is overkill since the high end for i is the low end for i-1. [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: This is a very poor choice of scenario for using a 2D array but then most scenarios used to teach the use of 2D arrays are.  2D arrays have their place but they should only be used when what you actually need is a matrix, i.e. where every element is a peer.  Anyway, the fact that you're using a 2D array is completely irrelevant to your question.  If you had to declare a variable that could store either an `Integer` value or a `String`, what type would you declare it?  That's the type you use for your array.

Comment: Thank you for the thought provoking response.  Although I don't know the answer to your question I now have something to research. Thanks again!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

2-dimensional array is correct. First index is column, second index is row.

```
Dim strData(,) As String 'Use String variable type, even for the numbers
Dim intRowCount As Integer = 5
Dim intColumnCount As Integer = 3
ReDim strData(intColumnCount - 1, intRowCount - 1) 'subtract 1 because array indices are 0-based. Column 0 = Range start, Column 1 = Range End, Column 2 = Grade
'first row
strData(0, 0) = "0" 'Range start
strData(1, 0) = "299" 'Range end
strData(2, 0) = "F" 'Grade
'second row
strData(0, 1) = "300"
strData(1, 1) = "349"
strData(2, 1) = "D"
'third row
strData(0, 2) = "350"
strData(1, 2) = "399"
strData(2, 2) = "C"
'fourth row
strData(0, 3) = "400"
strData(1, 3) = "449"
strData(2, 3) = "B"
'fifth row
strData(0, 4) = "450"
strData(1, 4) = "500"
strData(2, 4) = "A"
'Add a row
intRowCount = intRowCount + 1
ReDim Preserve strData(intColumnCount - 1, intRowCount - 1)
'sixth row
strData(0, 5) = "501"
strData(1, 5) = "600"
strData(2, 5) = "A+"
```

Note that `Redim Preserve` can only change the last index in the array, which is why we store in `(column, row)` order rather than the more traditional `(row, column)` order.

Comment: Great example of how to work with 2-dimensional array in VB.

Comment: I typically think of the first index as the row and the second index as the column. Anyone else think this way too? It doesn't really matter if you're writing and reading the data, but if you're working with external code I'm just curious if there that is typically how it is done.

Comment: Good question! Usually you add rows and `Redim Preserve` only works on the last index. This means the last index is usually the row

Comment: Then that totally makes to do it that way in VB. Great answer! With most other languages (from a quick Google search) it appears that the row is usually the first index, followed by the columns [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm), but again can be a personal preference.

Comment: Most other languages don't have re-sizable arrays like VB ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. One is to declare the array as Object type, and they assign integers or strings to the appropriate element. Some don't consider this socially acceptable, though, because it can lead to code that's difficult to debug.

You could also use a String type for a two dimensional array and save the integers in string variables. This is also not normally done because of the conversion necessary for numeric comparisons and computation.

Another approach is to use a structure or class that contains the three values, and make an array of that.

For example,

```
Structure Item
  Dim col1 as integer
  Dim col2 as integer
  Dim col3 as string
  End Structure

Dim itemList(20) as Item

itemList(4).col1 = 23
itemList(4).col2 = 45
itemList(4).col3 = "somestring"
```

Comment: In the real world, I'd recommend using a System.Data.DataTable

Comment: Using structures or classes is a great idea. It generally makes life much easier.