# hard-code a numeric table in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a numeric table (10 rows, 5 columns) that i want to have in my code. It means i don't want to read it from external source in my code.

What is the best way to hard-code a table in VB.NET? **Arrays**, **List**, or anything else ?  The correct way should have as little code as possible for adding numeric data.

I already tried this code to escape from defining each element in one line, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim b(2, 2) As Integer
b(0) = {5, 2}, {4, 3}
```

Comment: If you're using a listview, just add the items directly.

Comment: Maybe a `DataTable`?

Comment: While they often get used by beginners in situations where they shouldn't, if your data represents a true matrix then a 2D array is probably the most appropriate data structure. That said, the best way to store the data depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: Why a negative score? Yes, it's like a matrix. In fact. it's a statistical table, mostly printed on the end of math books. It is used to retrieve data based on first element in row and first element in column. I mean retrieving data is by intersection of first row (as column header) and first column (as row header).

Comment: @ALalavi Most people leave a negative score if it isn't a "my code doesn't work heres the code" question. Dunno why, but they do :P

Comment: @Jaxi, it's because that's what this site is for. SO is not for questions like "how do I do this general thing". It's for questions like "I want to do this specific thing, this is how I tried to do it and this is what happened when I tried it". There are other sites that are intended for the first type of question, including some also on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @jmcihinney, It's not about "How do i do this thing". I know solutions for that problem which need a lot of code. But i'm looking the best code-saving solution. The main problem goes to adding numeric data to the solution. look at my comment below first answer.

Comment: @ALalavi, and SO is NOT for questions on how to optimise code. It's for questions on code that is meant to do something specific but doesn't. Also, your question IS general. It may be the intention that the answer is used in a specific situation but you haven't described that specific situation so your question is not specific.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I added the way i passed and wrong codes i tried to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [List of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478600/add-a-list-into-another-list-in-vb-net) - pretty simple for both adding and reading data

```
Dim lst As New List(Of Int16) From {11,222,33}
```

2) [3D Array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arrays.htm) - you needt to handle the size of array correctly. In this case, where you have a fixed set of data it is easy too.

3) Structure - easy data access, but a bit complicated in setting up

```
Dim arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

- credits to jmcilhinney comments bellow

Here is a post both with [array and structure answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111008/declaring-two-dimensional-array).

Comment: The problem with List, structures, and 2D arrays is that for every number in table (10 rows, 5 columns = 50 number), i have to write a line of code for adding that number. I was thinking that Jagged arrays (array of arrays) may need little coding for adding number. I'm also going to try List(of array).

Comment: But 10 rows 5 columns is a simple 2D array. As for Array, you don't have to write a line of code for every number - you need to write a line of code for every row. You do have to do that for a list, but it's pretty simple: Lst.Add(123)

Comment: A multi-dimensional array does not require you to write a line of code for each element. You can write a literal array if it's hard-coded or nested loops if it's read from an external source.

Comment: Dim arr As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}

Comment: @Oak_3260548, "you need to write a line of code for every row". Nope. E.g. `Dim arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`.  Tada!  A 2x2 array in one line.  You can extrapolate that to as many columns, rows and dimensions as you want.

Comment: A `List(Of T)` can also be initialised in much the same way as a 1D array using the `From` keyword.

Comment: Thanks all. It was my fault. at first, i was trying to add like this: arr(0) = {1,2} (a line of code for every row), which throws exception. Defining all elements at once, as @ jmcihinney stated,is the best.